# Is Geth syncing?

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, geth-debugging, snapshot

I started a Geth instance in snap mode, it's been running for 3 days now.

The log is constantly showing:

```
Feb 23 19:01:01 ns516963 geth[36263]: INFO [02-23|19:01:01.940] Forkchoice requested sync to new head    number=19,292,239 hash=d024a6..3ced2b finalized=19,292,153
Feb 23 19:01:03 ns516963 geth[36263]: INFO [02-23|19:01:03.889] Syncing: state healing in progress       accounts=4834@243.64KiB slots=819@68.06KiB codes=386@2.91MiB nodes=2,133,293@632.28MiB>
Feb 23 19:01:04 ns516963 geth[36263]: INFO [02-23|19:01:04.349] Syncing: chain download in progress      synced=100.00% chain=698.50GiB headers=19,292,239@8.93GiB bodies=19,292,155@510.36GiB >
Feb 23 19:01:11 ns516963 geth[36263]: INFO [02-23|19:01:11.918] Syncing: state healing in progress       accounts=4849@244.35KiB slots=820@68.14KiB codes=386@2.91MiB nodes=2,133,472@632.35MiB>
Feb 23 19:01:12 ns516963 geth[36263]: INFO [02-23|19:01:12.358] Syncing: chain download in progress      synced=100.00% chain=698.50GiB headers=19,292,239@8.93GiB bodies=19,292,155@510.36GiB >
Feb 23 19:01:13 ns516963 geth[36263]: INFO [02-23|19:01:13.768] Forkchoice requested sync to new head    number=19,292,240 hash=4d6faa..c863a6 finalized=19,292,153
Feb 23 19:01:20 ns516963 geth[36263]: INFO [02-23|19:01:20.363] Syncing: chain download in progress      synced=100.00% chain=698.50GiB headers=19,292,240@8.93GiB bodies=19,292,155@510.36GiB >
```

The size of the node was constantly increasing, but now it's stuck at ~960GB.

eth.syncing returns:

```json
{
  currentBlock: 19292155,
  healedBytecodeBytes: 3047982,
  healedBytecodes: 386,
  healedTrienodeBytes: 664251530,
  healedTrienodes: 2136901,
  healingBytecode: 0,
  healingTrienodes: 1108,
  highestBlock: 19292253,
  startingBlock: 19291830,
  syncedAccountBytes: 58583947891,
  syncedAccounts: 259488246,
  syncedBytecodeBytes: 8275737386,
  syncedBytecodes: 1185791,
  syncedStorage: 1152783728,
  syncedStorageBytes: 248418971697,
  txIndexFinishedBlocks: 0,
  txIndexRemainingBlocks: 1
}
```

eth.blockNumber always returns 0. Not sure if I'm missing something or if is it normal and I just have to wait.